# Unserialize - Error at offset 0 of 64 bytes

Tags: php, serialization

Getting this error :

```
echo $addressStr;
$address = unserialize($addressStr);
```

Echo returns

```
2:{i:0;s:18:"address:1,NN15 6TU";i:1;s:18:"address:8,NN15 6TU";}
```

Error returns

> Notice: unserialize() [function.unserialize]: Error at offset 0 of 64 bytes in C:\wamp\www\guild_service\server\map_view.php on line 115

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your string is indeed something missing. I think it may need 'a:' in the front