# ununserialize is not working in php function

Tags: php, mysql

I need to display unserialized data from serialized data of mysql. I stored a data in serialized method in mysql by following below:

```
'a:4:{s:16:"degree_completed";s:3:"Yes";s:10:"experience";s:3:"Yes";s:8:"exp_year";s:1:"3";s:9:"exp_month";s:1:"5";}'
```

Here, I want unserialized it and display in php. When I try `unserialize()`, it shows the error is:

```
Notice: unserialize(): Error at offset 0 of 115 bytes
```

So any one can help me?

Comment: Show what you've tried.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7336311/unserialize-error-at-offset-0-of-64-bytes

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your serialized data. I will unserialize correctly, unless something is happening is happening that is not recorded in the question, which is why @Adelphia asked for the code.

Comment: Only your code can tell your mistake here

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
$Str = 'a:4:{s:16:"degree_completed";s:3:"Yes";s:10:"experience";s:3:"Yes";s:8:"exp_year";s:1:"3";s:9:"exp_month";s:1:"5";}'; 
$Str_new = unserialize($Str);
print_r($Str_new);
```

Comment: it shows same error when i try your cod - Bindiya Patoliya

Comment: here i need to get only "degree_completed" value i.e "Yes"